# Error: Memory operand not allowed in context

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x87

```
.code
orderTotal db 0.0

Burger:
    fadd dword ptr [orderTotal], 10
    jmp Food

Pizza:
    fadd dword ptr [orderTotal], 16
    jmp Food

ChickenRice:
    fadd dword ptr [orderTotal], 8
    jmp Food
```

It is supposed to add value into `orderTotal`, but I end up with `memory operand not allowed in context` error.

Comment: x87 instructions don't work with immediates or with memory destinations.  Read the manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fadd:faddp:fiadd) and a tutorial (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Also you declared orderTotal as a byte which is too small. You're going to need to use a `dword` at a minimum

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> orderTotal db 0.0
> ```

This is not how you define a real number. Use:

- `REAL4` for single precision floating point values (4 bytes)
- `REAL8` for double precision floating point values (8 bytes)
- `REAL10` for extended precision floating point values (10 bytes)

The arithmetic operations that the FPU (Floating Point Unit) does, all happen *within* the FPU. You need to load operands from / store results to memory:

```
orderTotal      REAL4 0.0
costBurger      SWORD 10
costPizza       SWORD 16
costChickenRice SWORD 10

...

Burger:
    mov  bx, OFFSET costBurger
    jmp  AddIt
Pizza:
    mov  bx, OFFSET costPizza
    jmp  AddIt
ChickenRice:
    mov  bx, OFFSET costChickenRice
AddIt:
    fld  orderTotal       ; Load ST0 from the short real in memory
    fiadd SWORD PTR [bx]  ; Raise ST0 by a signed word in memory
    fstp orderTotal       ; Store ST0 to the short real in memory
                          ; - because of the 'p', ST0 is freed on the FPU stack
    jmp  Food
```